# External storage device formating error?

Tags: macos, hard-drive, time-machine, disk-utility

Trying to repair an external storage device in Disk Utility I first clicked "Verify Disk..." and then "Repair Disk..." but i got the below error:

> Verify and Repair volume “disk3s2”
>   Repairing file system.
>   ** /dev/rdisk3s2
>   Invalid BS_jmpBoot in boot block: cc4542
>   File system check exit code is 8.
>   Updating boot support partitions for the volume as required.
>   Error: Disk Utility can’t repair this disk. Back up as many of your files as possible, reformat the disk, and restore your backed-up files.

How do I solve the problem?

Specs: OS X Yosemite 10.10.5

Comment: Please add the output of `sudo gpt -r show disk3` (or the respective disk identifier of the external drive) entered in Terminal.app to your question by editing it in!

Answer (score 3):

You could easily wipe the drive and start fresh - use care that disk 3 is really the disk you wish to erase everything.

```
diskutil eraseDisk JHFS+ UntitledUFS disk3
```

If that fails, you likely have a hardware error (unless the failure is your OS or not using an account with `sudo` permissions). If that succeeds, you could then use Disk Utility to rename things as you please or learn more about `diskutil` and use it to rename / repartition / reformat the drive going forward.

Comment: Reading the question I'd assume that the disk/volume holds some data/content **and** the OP has **no**  backup. This is no good advice without mentioning that the data is gone after executing the above command.

Comment: it was a bootable drive ,,previously ..., i dont want the data in the drive ..and what is this line of error ......>>>---- Invalid BS_jmpBoot in boot block: cc4542